# build gradle: Invalid variable name,Must start with a letter but was 'lib'

Tags: android, parse-platform

[enter image description here][1]**strong text**[enter image description here][2]

Im new on android ..and facing this problem to start parse server

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yasir.jsaljlaj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.3'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile fileTree(dir:’libs’,include:[‘*.jar’])
}
```

and this is the error

Error:(37, 0) startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\yasir\Downloads\Jsaljlaj\app\build.gradle': 37: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ’libs’
. At [37:26]  @ line 37, column 26.
       compile fileTree(dir:’libs’,include:[‘*.jar’])
                            ^

1 error

Open File

Comment: Please put the code and error text in in the question and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Put the compile fileTree line inside your dependencies brackets.

Also note, you should have only one dependency section, so

```
dependecies{
//all your dependencies here
}
```

**EDIT**

Remove the last line of code before brackets:

```
compile fileTree(dir:’libs’,include:[‘*.jar’]);
```

Remove this and everything is alright

Comment: @YasiirKhanY'x show us your build gradle, edit your question and post whole build.gradle file

Comment: compile fileTree(dir:’libs’,include:[‘*.jar’])
and its saying invalid variable name,must start with a letter but was :'libs'

Comment: @YasiirKhanY'x edit your question and put whole build.gradle

Comment: @YasiirKhanY'x if the answer helped you, please accept it